# Can you add CSS to the child of a CSS class created by custom fields?

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I have created a custom field to allow me to add css to the entry header on specific pages. The custom field give meta data of either hide_title_yes or hide_title_no via a radio button in the edit page window, using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I've then used that meta data to create a custom css class.

```
<?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hide_title'); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($custom_values); ?>>
```

The problem is the CSS class is added to the article element not the header element. Is there a way I can select the header element from the article element?

```
    <article id="post-19" class="hide_title_yes post-19 page type-page status-publish hentry">
```

I have tried using

```
article > header .entry-header {
left: -999em;
position: absolute;
}
```

to select the header element where the article is the parent element. But i think I may have misunderstood the use of the selector.

01/05 Update: I've added a screenshot of the HTML structure.
[HTML Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD6Rj.png)

01/05 Update 2: I've now added the following code:

```
<header class="entry-header<?php echo get_field('hide_title') ? ' yes' : '' ?>">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        <?php twentyseventeen_edit_link( get_the_ID() ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

The css class is now added to the entry-header

```
<header class="entry-header yes">
```

However when I try to target that class in my css file it doesn't work. The code in the css file is:

```
header.entry-header.yes {
    left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

When I add the code into Google inspector it works. So i'm obviously not targeting the class correctly.

Comment: share the html structure to be able to tell you if the selector is correct or not

Comment: Is `header`  a child of `article` or the other way around?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added an image of the html structure to the post

Comment: @JonP Header is a child of article

Comment: There is conflicting information in you question. You state " the CSS class is added to the article element not the header element" yet your code shows the class added to the `header` element. Which is it?  Your code provided does not show the `section` element. Please provide a [MCVE] with HTML as rendered, not the PHP.

Comment: @JonP Sorry for the confusion and incomplete example Jon. I'm new to this so I'm sorry if i've missed anything out. I've edited my original post and added the original code and how it rendered. I have solved the first part of the problem, in that I have now managed to add the class to the header element. However I now don't seem to be able to target the class in CSS

Comment: Your selector works with the code supplied: https://jsfiddle.net/s7ey1tv9/ . You are possibly running into a [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue. Inspect the header element with the Developer Tools in the browser of your choice, this will tell you what styles have been applied and what is being over ridden and from where. Also make sure to flush your browser cache.

Comment: @JonP Thanks for your help, it was indeed a specificity issue. I added in an ID and it's now working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class on a header (header.php) by checking condition hide_title_yes and than target that class in your css file.

Comment: I've updated my post. I have managed to add the class 'yes' to the class entry-header

However I can't target it properly in the css. If I try in google inspector it works so I'm obviously not targeting the class correctly

Comment: can i see your site where you are implementing?

Comment: header.entry-header.yes {
    left: -999em !important;
    position: absolute  !important;
}
Try this